# How to handle abort in test unit

Tags: unit-testing, rust, abort

I want to test one of my function that should panic, but my GitHub action `abort()` cause even if my code is asking for "only" `2**31` bytes (In my real code the limit is `libc::c_int::MAX`) that my PC has, GitHub action don't have such memory :p.

```rust
#[test]
#[should_panic]
fn reserve_with_max() {
    Vec::with_capacity(usize::MAX);
}
```

But this fails with:

```
test tests::bad_fd ... ok
test tests::create_true ... ok
test tests::create_false ... ok
test tests::create_with_one ... ok
memory allocation of 25769803764 bytes failed
```

And this stops the testing and report an error, even if this what I expected (either panic or abort).

I didn't find much about this problem:

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67650
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/fn.set_alloc_error_hook.html (but nightly)

I expect there should be a `#[should_abort]`, how could I handle this ?

For now my obvious solution is to `ignore` the test:

```rust
#[test]
#[should_panic]
#[ignore = "Ask too much memory"]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be considered a bug in GitHub Actions implementation ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret hard to say, technically, I don't actually use this memory, I just do a `with_capacity()` even in my real code so the memory could stay totally virtual and never be allocated by OS. But nothing disallow github action to report an oom (and this expected when you ask this much memory). I think I will remove this test at the end, I don't like it but I think the question is still interesting, we can clearly see that testing abort is not easily with cargo.

Answer (score 1):

You could fork the test but there is a lot of cons:

- need nix (maybe there is a OS agnostic fork crate somewhere...)
- test code become complex
- code coverage tool problem
- ask more resource
- hacky

```rust
#[test]
#[ignore = "Still ignored taupaulin doesn't like it too"]
fn create_with_max() {
    use nix::{
        sys::{
            signal::Signal,
            wait::{waitpid, WaitStatus},
        },
        unistd::{fork, ForkResult},
    };
    use std::panic;
    use std::process::abort;

    match unsafe { fork() } {
        Ok(ForkResult::Parent { child }) => match waitpid(child, None) {
            Ok(WaitStatus::Signaled(_, s, _)) => {
                if s != Signal::SIGABRT {
                    panic!("Didn't abort")
                }
            }
            o => panic!("Didn't expect: {:?}", o),
        },
        Ok(ForkResult::Child) => {
            let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
                Vec::with_capacity(usize::MAX);
            });

            if let Err(_) = result {
                abort();
            }
        }
        Err(_) => panic!("Fork failed"),
    }
}
```

I don't think I would advice this.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [RFC 2116](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/161ce8a26e70226a88e0d4d43c7914a714050330/text/2116-alloc-me-maybe.md) that would allow to configure rust to make out of memory panic instead of `abort()`:

```
[profile.dev]
oom = "panic"

[profile.release]
oom = "panic"
```

Cons:

- Not implemented even on nightly [#43596](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43596)
- It's will work for your use case cause it's an oom abort but it's not a general solution for handle `abort()` in test.

Comment: Technically, you can always run `kill -ABRT $pid_of_test` which should *probably* never be considered a successful test. So I don't know how useful a *general purpose* `abort()` "handler" would be.

Comment: @trentcl yes, this solution would be perfect in my case, I don't think abort is mean to be handle at all, I just happen to not have a choice cause of current std state.